# how to assign array values to individual int variables using scala

Tags: scala

I am trying achieve the below in scala

```
var date="12/01/2021"
var a,b,c = date.split("/")
print(a,b,c)

//expected result 
12,01,2021
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you know for sure the size of the array after splitting, which is why you cannot destructure it like this.

However you can use pattern matching:

```scala
date.split("/") match {
  case Array(a, b, c) => print(...)
  case _ => print("invalid format")
}
```

Or just access the array by index (not safe):

```scala
val arr = date.split("/")
val (a, b, c) = (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
val Array(a,b,c) = date.split("/")
```

or

```
val Array(a,b,c) = date.split("/").take(3)
```

However, the pattern match as @Gaël J suggested has the advantage of graceful handling of cases where the result doesn't have the 3 parts expected

Answer (score 0):

You can pattern match directly on the `date` String (based on Gaël's answer)

```
val date = "12/01/2021"
date match {
  case s"$a/$b/$c" => print(a, b, c)
  case _ => print("invalid format")
}
```